how to connect PowerBI and Odoo 17 with ODBC driver
I would like to know how to connect Power BI and Odoo using an ODBC driver. I have tried several methods but have not found a free version that works with Odoo 17. If you have any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated.
I tried using PostgreSQL directly, but it wasn't very helpful because I need the data from Odoo itself.

Why wasn't it helpful to use the direct connection to the database? Odoo itself is using the database to store everything, except for attachments/files.
